# Bracha on Dead Sea

Tags: halacha, blessing, eretz-yisrael

According to Halacha (Shulchan Oruch, Orach Chaim 228:1) one says עושה מעשה בראשית on seeing the sea.
Does one make a Bracha on seeing the Dead Sea?
Is it a proper sea? If so, what is the correct Bracha? Appreciate sources.

Answer (score 6):

Bottom line, it's a machlokes.. [Dose of Halacha](http://doseofhalacha.blogspot.co.uk/2015/06/seeing-sea.html) writes:

> While R’ Benzion Abba Shaul (Ohr Letzion 2:14:40n) writes that one should say ..oseh maaseh bereishis upon seeing the Dead Sea, R’ Shlomo Zalman Auerbach (Halichos Shlomo 23:n43) and R’ Shmuel Wosner (Shevet Halevi 9:47) held that one doesn’t recite a beracha as it was not created during the Six Days of Creation (Rashi, Bereishis 14:3).

Answer (score 1):

Just one more source to add to @Zvi's answer. It is worth noting the Shibbolei HaLeket....

HaRav Chaim Bleier in this week's [Chukei Chaim (Parshas Vaeschanan 5781)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nhLGhwF1-RiJKRvFtzvNQIn6x1N9nZiL/view?usp=sharing) - I'll link once online, writes as follows:

> Although the Dead Sea is one of the wonders of the world, it is unclear if it gets a bracha so one should not say "עושה מעשה בראשית". The reason for this is because it is apparent from Chazal (ע"י [רש"י בראשית י"ד](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.14.3?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.14.3.2&lang2=bi) עה"פ עמק השידים) that the Dead Sea did not exist since creation; rather channels of water flowed to the area, resulting in the Dead Sea (שו"ת שבה"ל ח"ט ס' מ"ז).

Comment: They will be uploaded here in about a week. this is the Chukai Chaim archives link.https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Kx3peNqwY53cJ6CmrH1fyJG8C7Pi4U3w. To see the issue that @Dov was quoting, I have temporarily uploaded them to here for 7 days. https://we.tl/t-LT36ubgbw9

Comment: Thanks @MiZeh !